# PostgreSQL - select alias

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Estoy migrando una base desde Sybase a PostgreSql (Versión 12) y aprendiendo de paso. Este select en sybase me funciona, pero con postgresql me acusa

> “NO EXISTE LA COLUMNA ls_numero”

```
select '1234567890' as ls_numero,
       substr(ls_numero, 3, 3);
```

como sería el código en postgresql?

---

bien, ahora imaginemos que '1234567890' es una funcion f_articulo_get_precio( id_articulo ), que devuelve en un string como el siguiente 'XXXZMMM1234567890123yyyy/mm/dd' donde 1234567890123 es el precio y yyyy/mm/dd la fecha en que se cambio por ultima vez. Como haria en este caso para obtener estos valores por separado? sin llamar a la funcion 2 veces?

Comment: Qué versión de PostgreSQL estás usando? Como recomendación, procura indicar siempre la versión del software en el que estás trabajando para poder ofrecer respuestas más efectivas

Comment: Si perdon, estoy usando la Version 12.

Comment: En postgresql la funcion me parece que es la siguiente: SUBSTRING( first_name, 1, 1 )

Comment: Un ejemplo simple es el siguiente: SELECT last_name, SUBSTRING( first_name, 1, 1 ) AS initial FROM customer

Comment: No conozco sybase, pero lo que intentas hacer no es posible en gran parte de las principales BDs, la columna `ls_numero` no se materializa hasta completar la consulta, por lo que no lo puedes reusar dentro del `select`.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice @PatricioMoracho , yo me equivoque y lei como que era un campo de tu DB

Answer (score 0):

Para tu versión de PostgreSQL es posible usar un [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) y el [substring](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) se declara como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo

```
WITH constant_tbl AS (
    SELECT cast('1234567890' as text) AS ls_numero
)
SELECT
SUBSTRING(ls_numero, 3, 3) as pepe
FROM constant_tbl
```

El casting de la constante es necesario porque usarla sin más [parece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770528/postgresql-error-failed-to-find-conversion-function-from-unknown-to-text) no gustarle a PostgreSQL (como no es una columna cuyo tipo conozca, no sabe cómo aplicar funciones de strings sobre ella).

La sugerencia de fondo es, entonces, guiarte siempre por la documentación oficial.